# sklearn GridSearchCV: how to get classification report?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, grid-search

I am using GridSearchCV like this:

```
corpus = load_files('corpus')

with open('stopwords.txt', 'r') as f:
    stop_words = [y for x in f.read().split('\n') for y in (x, x.title())]

x = corpus.data

y = corpus.target

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vec', CountVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
    ('classifier', MultinomialNB())])

parameters = {'vec__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],
              'classifier__alpha': [1e-2, 1e-3],
              'classifier__fit_prior': [True, False]}

gs_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, cv=5, scoring="f1", verbose=10)

gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(x, y)

joblib.dump(gs_clf.best_estimator_, 'MultinomialNB.pkl', compress=1)
```

Then, in another file, to classify new documents (not from the corpus), I do this:

```
  classifier = joblib.load(filepath) # path to .pkl file
  result = classifier.predict(tokenlist)
```

My question is: Where do I get the values needed for the `classification_report`?

In many other examples, I see people split the corpus into traing set and test set.
However, since I am using `GridSearchCV` with kfold-cross-validation, I don't need to do that.
So how can I get those values from `GridSearchCV`?

Comment: Just a question, doesn't `gs_clf.fit(x, y)` return `None`?

Comment: @BallpointBen Why would it? x and y contain data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best model is in clf.best_estimator_. You need to fit the training data to this; then predict your test data and use ytest and ypreds for the classification report.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So just to be clear: for the GridSearchCV I use all of the data (corpus,data and corpus.target in my case) but for the best classifier, I partition the data into x_test, X_train, Y_test, Y_train using train_test_split?

Comment: Yes. If you want the scores to be reliable then they need to measure against a different set of data to the set used for fitting.

Comment: Or if you have enough data you could split the data before doing gridsearch.

Comment: And then instead of passing corpus.data to GridSearch, I only pass X_train?

Answer (score 6):

If you have GridSearchCV object:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
clf = GridSearchCV(....)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
classification_report(y_test,clf.best_estimator_.predict(x_test))
```

If you have saved the best estimator and loaded it then:

```
classifier = joblib.load(filepath)
classification_report(y_test,classifier.predict(x_test))
```